# jQuery form action change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally to change the action attribute of a form in jQuery I would do the following:

```
<form id="removeLightboxForm" action="">
...
</form>

$('#removeLightboxForm').attr("action", "view/#close");
```

But I usually use this for when the action attribute is empty on the HTML form tag itself. I'm now trying to use this on a form where the action attribute already contains a default URL and is causing problems.

In this example, the form action is present:

```
<form id="removeLightboxForm" action="view/">
...
</form>
```

But when I do this:

```
$('#removeLightboxForm').attr("action", "view/#close");
```

I end up with the new URL/action being added to the original URL/action, for example:

```
<form action="view/view/#close" ...
```

Is this how it's supposed to work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the problem (I assume it's something earlier in your code), but if this is happening then why not just append the hash to the `action` attribute? `attr("action", "#close")`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7U4qB/ If I inspect the form with google chrome it has the appropriate action.  Can you provide an example illustrating it not working?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've tried resetting the attribute before updating it, as  Adam suggested below, and works. I think I need to investigate further as to why I'm getting such behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try clearing it first:

```
$('#removeLightboxForm').attr("action", "").attr("action", "view/#close");
```

or

```
$('#removeLightboxForm').removeAttr("action").attr("action", "view/#close");
```

Comment: This worked for now, thanks, still going to investigate why it's happening - it's weird!

Comment: @MartinG - glad it worked.  Not sure why you needed that.  Just a wild guess, but maybe modify your original code to `$().attr("action", "/view/#close");`  (note the leading slash)